# Issue with Dual Boot Linux - [ 1.707005] Couldn't get size: 0x80000000e

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios

Woke up this morning to this issue. Can somebody help?

All I'm getting is an error, BusyBox and (initramfs). This is the second time an installation of Linux bricks itself on my PC.

The last time I had the error:

```
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer
```

I'm running the latest version of Kubuntu on an HP Pavilion x360 laptop. Please help!

Comment: If the error message identified the partition, then enter `fsck /dev/sdax`. Otherwise, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: Alright I'll try this out and get back to you, thanks

Comment: It's working great now, thanks! Really didn't want to go back to windows.